# In SQLite how do I copy data from one column to another column in the same table?

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite how to copy data from one column to another column in same database table?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableName SET destinationField = sourceField
```

Comment: What if that results in `foreign key mismatch - "someOtherTable" referencing "tableName": UPDATE tableName SET destinationField = sourceField`? (where `someOtherTable` references the source field, which we're not touching).

Comment: This sql may require where clause, so just add `where 1=1` at the end of script!